# difference between memory at and ptr in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, addressing-mode

Back at it with another assembly question. I am having a hard time seeing what is the difference between square brackets and ptr in assembly.

```
mov dword ptr eax, 1234 ; this should write 1234 to the memory address stored at eax right?
mov dword ptr [eax], 1234; this writes to the memory address that is stored at the memory address that is stored in eax?
mov [eax], 1234 ; this does the same as the first one right? it writes 1234 to the memory address that is stored in eax?
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this topic?

Comment: Does the first one even assemble?  What assembler are you using?  Assuming MASM, see [Confusing brackets in MASM32](//stackoverflow.com/q/25129743).  See also [x86, difference between BYTE and BYTE PTR](//stackoverflow.com/q/13790146).  Your last line is an error in most assemblers; neither operand implies a size.

Comment: i'm learning MASM, so thats what the question is related to.

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler not the target, so in the future put the assembler and as needed version in the question.

Answer (score 4):

`dword PTR` is just a size specifier for what follows. Since the size of `eax` is known, the `dword PTR` is redundant in the first case.

That is, `mov dword ptr eax, 1234` is the same as just writing `mov eax, 1234`.

`mov dword ptr [eax], 1234` means *write 1234 to the doubleword in memory at the address given by `eax`*.

`mov [eax], 1234` is ambigous and shouldn't even assemble. The assembler has no way of knowing if you intended to store a word or a doubleword.